# How to stop a process from being closed after certain signal is sent?

Tags: c, unix, signals, fork, kill

I need to create a program, which will create child process that will handle processes. In case of SIGXCPU called, child process should close, but when other signal is received, process shouldn't close, but display information. How could I change signals_handler function to stop closing my process?

I call signals from second terminal window.

```
void signals_handler(int signal) {
   psignal(signal,"\nRecived signal");
   printf("Signal number is: %d\n", signal);
   return;
}

void sig_XCPU(int signal() {
   signal(XCPU, sig_XCPU);
}
```

...

```
int main(void)
{

   if(fork() == 0) {
   print("PID: %d", getpid();
   signal(SIGXCPU, sig_xcpu)
   for(int = 1; i < 65; i++) {
       if(i != 24) //SIGXCPU number
       signal(i, signals_handler);
   }
   sleep(100);
   return 0;
   }
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test like this:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void signal_handle(int sig) {
  switch (sig) {
  case SIGXCPU: {
    char st[] = "child recesive SIGXCPU, quit\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, st, sizeof(st));
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    break;
  }
  case SIGINT: {
    char st[] = "child recesive SIGINT\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, st, sizeof(st));
    break;
  }
  default: break;
  }
 return;
}

void set_signal() {
  signal(SIGXCPU, signal_handle);
  signal(SIGINT,  signal_handle);
}

int main() {
  pid_t pid = fork(); 
  if (pid == 0) { // child
    set_signal();
    char st[] = "child set signal\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, st, sizeof(st));
    for (;;)
      ;
  }
  // parent
  sleep(3); // wait child set_signal
  // test SIGINT
  {
    char st[] = "parent send SIGINT\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, st, sizeof(st));
    kill(pid, SIGINT);
  }
  sleep(3);

  // test SIGXCPU 
  {
    char st[] = "parent send SIGXCPU\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, st, sizeof(st));
    kill(pid, SIGXCPU);
  }
  wait(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```